# Write a string inside a PHP file

Tags: php

Is it possible to put a string inside a PHP file? 
 Example:

```
<?php
$user["Stack"] = "oveflow";
?>
```

And when users write another string it became:

```
<?php
$user["Face"] = "book";
$user["Stack"] = "overflow";
?>
```

Any code that  **write a string inside a PHP file?**

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to be modifying code with code (you run the risk of executing user input as code). Why not edit a text file and have php load that data into an array?

Comment: Ok thanks for the idea that i'm gonna use a text file but can you teach me how to does the PHP code reads the file or array the content of the text file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = 'file.txt';
$data = 'dummydata';
file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it only overwrite the main file :(

Comment: so what you have to do, can please elaborate on it ?

Comment: When the users press a button it's gonna add a string to the PHP file, example: the unmodified version of the PHP code is: <?php $hello ?>, when the user press a button, it gonna modify the PHP code by adding a string and it's gonna look like this: <?php $hello; $stackoverflow; ?>. I am very new to PHP programming so i'm a beginner here

Comment: Means you want to modify and append file.txt rite ?

Comment: Actually a wanted to modify the content of the file.php :)

Comment: Sorry you can't do that directly. What you can do is create an array of strings in php file and on button press add new data to text file and php file will read file.txt content and add data to arrays of string

Comment: So, the data is gonna be on a text file and the PHP gonna array it? Can you please teach me sensei? It is great tho :)

Comment: and btw can I have a chat on you? IRC or on Facebook? cause I can't have chat on this website cause I only have 10 rep (i'm a starter here in this website tho)

Comment: Sure ping me at kadakiaruchit@gmail.com

Comment: I'll send you an email :) Thanks for being there for me, I hope that all of the programmers are kind and nice like you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it allows you to easily put and get data persistently:

```
<?php

class Storage {
    private static $file = 'data.json';
    private static $data = null;

    private static function preload() {
        if (is_null(self::$data))
            self::$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(self::$file), true);
    }

    public static function put($key, $value) {
        self::preload();
        self::$data[$key] = $value;
        file_put_contents(self::$file, json_encode(self::$data));
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        self::preload();
        return isset(self::$data[$key]) ? self::$data[$key] : null;
    }
}

Storage::put("Stack", "oveflow");
Storage::put("Face", "book");

echo Storage::get("Stack") . "<br>\n";
echo Storage::get("Face");
```

After you put the data once, it will always be there. You can run this script once, then remove:

```
Storage::put("Stack", "oveflow");
Storage::put("Face", "book");
```

And run it again and you will still see the two echo outputs.